# get text paragraph from pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-parsing

is there any logic to get paragraph text from pdf file using itextsharp?i know pdf only supports run of texts and its hard to determine which runs of texts are related to which paragraph and also i know that there isn't any `<p>` tags or other tags to determine paragraph in pdf..However i have tried to get coordinate of runs of texts to build paragraph from its coordinate but with no luck :(.
my code snippet is here:

```
private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    private Vector lastBaseLine;
    //to store run of texts 
    public List<string> strings = new List<String>();
    //to store run of texts Coordinate (Y coordinate)
    public List<float> baselines = new List<float>();

    public void RenderText(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        Vector curBaseline = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
        if ((this.lastBaseLine != null) && (curBaseline[Vector.I2] != lastBaseLine[Vector.I2]))
        {
            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.result.ToString())))
            {
                this.baselines.Add(this.lastBaseLine[Vector.I2]);
                this.strings.Add(this.result.ToString());
            }
            result = new StringBuilder();
        }
        this.result.Append(renderInfo.GetText());
        this.lastBaseLine = curBaseline;
    }
```

Do any body have any logic related to this issue??

Comment: Is your PDF a Tagged PDF? If it isn't, there's no easy way to determine which text snippets belong to which paragraph (but you already discovered that).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanx for your respone ,PDF isn't tagged PDF..isn't there any solution to extract paragraph from Not Tagged PDF???

Comment: No 100% proof solutions, merely heuristics with smaller or larger failure rates.

Comment: +1 for @mkl He's right.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
   PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
   document.Open();
   document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
   document.Close();
   writer.Close();
   Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
   "attachment;filename=First PDF document.pdf");
   Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
}
```

[here are some samples which ll help you on this....](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/)

This is may not be exactly your looking for, but it may help you..

Comment: thanks for your answer but my concern is to read texts as paragraph from a pdf not to write pdf.